# How do I create a Keywords column using extracted keywords in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nlp

I have a dataframe which has 3columns and more than 10k records. The Dataframe looks like this:

```
 _id  page_number                        pdf_name text_data
0  60f1530e3249c01351086b2f          1.0  a.pdf        This is my timee,eerwff..
1  60f1530e3249c01351086b30          2.0  a.pdf        how is it going, tbh you nee..
2  60f1530e3249c01351086b31          3.0  a.pdf        mark marquez is, going to..
3  60f1530e3249c01351086b32          4.0  b.pdf        coronavirus seems to be...
4  60f1530e3249c01351086b33          5.0  b.pdf        sports all over,has,lost..
```

I have used the Countvectorizer from sklearn alongwith tfidf_transformers to get the keywords. at present I am getting the keywords extracted but they're only coming out for the last sentence.
Here is my code which extracts and then gives me the keywords.

```
for i in range(0, 10124):
    # Remove punctuations
    text = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', df['text_data'][i])

    # Convert to lowercase
    text = text.lower()

    # remove tags
    text = re.sub("&lt;/?.*?&gt;", " &lt;&gt; ", text)

    ##Convert to list from string
    text = text.split()

    ##Stemming
    ps = PorterStemmer()
    # Lemmatisation
    lem = WordNetLemmatizer()
    text = [lem.lemmatize(word) for word in text if not word in stop_words]
    text = " ".join(text)
    corpus.append(text)

# print(corpus)
cv = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.8, stop_words=stop_words, max_features=10000,
                     ngram_range=(1, 3))  # max_df= ignore words that appear in 80% of documents
# max features= the size of the vocabulary, ngram is vocabulary contains single words, bigrams, trigrams
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer(smooth_idf=True, use_idf=True)
tfidf_transformer.fit(X)
# get feature names
feature_names = cv.get_feature_names()

# fetch document for which keywords needs to be extracted
doc = corpus[-1]

# generate tf-idf for the given document
tf_idf_vector = tfidf_transformer.transform(cv.transform([doc]))


# Function for sorting tf_idf in descending order


def sort_coo(coo_matrix):
    tuples = zip(coo_matrix.col, coo_matrix.data)
    return sorted(tuples, key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)


def extract_topn_from_vector(feature_names, sorted_items):
    """get the feature names and tf-idf score of top n items"""

    # use only topn items from vector
    # sorted_items = sorted_items[:topn]

    score_vals = []
    feature_vals = []

    # word index and corresponding tf-idf score
    for idx, score in sorted_items:
        # keep track of feature name and its corresponding score
        score_vals.append(round(score, 3))
        feature_vals.append(feature_names[idx])

    # create a tuples of feature,score
    # results = zip(feature_vals,score_vals)
    results = {}
    for idx in range(len(feature_vals)):
        results[feature_vals[idx]] = score_vals[idx]

    return results


# sort the tf-idf vectors by descending order of scores
sorted_items = sort_coo(tf_idf_vector.tocoo())
# extract only the top n; n here is 10
keywords = extract_topn_from_vector(feature_names, sorted_items)

# print the results
print("\nAbstract:")
print(doc)
print("\nKeywords:")
for k in keywords:
    print(k, keywords[k])
```

which gives me an output like

```
Keywords:
market trend 0.613
trends 0.482
customers 0.366
best product 0.353
cameras 0.348
cameras on sale 0.082
discount 0.081
```

How do I ensure that I get keywords for all my records in the dataframe?
The end result that I want is a dataframe with 4columns having values:

```
_id  page_number                        pdf_name text_data                           Keywords
0  60f1530e3249c01351086b2f          1.0  a.pdf        This is my timee,eerwff.. time,
1  60f1530e3249c01351086b30          2.0  a.pdf        how is it going, tbh you nee.. going,
2  60f1530e3249c01351086b31          3.0  a.pdf        mark marquez is, going to.. mark,
3  60f1530e3249c01351086b32          4.0  b.pdf        coronavirus seems to be... corona,
4  60f1530e3249c01351086b33          5.0  b.pdf        sports all over,has,lost.. sports,
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: you get only the last sentence because in your code, `doc` is define as the last data from your dataframe with `corpus[-1]`, then using this in to get `tf_idf_vector = ... ` at the following line gives you the keywords only for this sentence/row. without recoding to much, you can do `df['keywords'] = [ ', '.join(list(extract_topn_from_vector(feature_names, sort_coo(tf_idf_vector.tocoo())).keys())[:n]) for tf_idf_vector in tfidf_transformer.transform(X) ]`  with n being the number of top n keywords you want to keep per row. if you want them all, then just remove `[:n]`

Comment: @Ben.T : thanks for your immediate response, using your logic, I added df['Keywords'] to the end of my script and it gave me the output when I print it.. Do I keep the doc=corpus[-1]

Comment: Indeed, you don't really need the part with `doc =... ` anymore if your goal is to have the column keywords